# Display dropdowns dynamically in one component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to have multiple dropdowns in one component using one variable to display or not and also clicking away from their div to close them:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button @click.prevent="isOpen = !isOpen"></button>
    <div v-show="isOpen">Content</div>
</div>
// second dropdown in same component
<div class="dropdown">
  <button @click.prevent="isOpen = !isOpen"></button>
    <div v-show="isOpen">Content</div>
</div>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    isOpen: false
  }
},
watch: {
  isOpen(isOpen) {
    if(isOpen) {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.closeIfClickedOutside)
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  closeIfClickedOutside(event){
    if(! event.target.closest('.dropdown')){
      this.isOpen = false;
    }
  }
}
```

But now when I click one dropdown menu it displays both of them. I am kinda new to vue and cant find way to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use just one variable for this, the variable needs to identify which dropdown is open, so it can't be a Boolean. I suggest storing the index (e.g., a number) in the variable, and conditionally render the selected dropdown by the index:

1. Declare a data property to store the selected index:

   ```js
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         selectedIndex: null
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Update `closeIfClickedOutside()` to clear the selected index, thereby closing the dropdowns:

   ```js
   export default {
     methods: {
       closeIfClickedOutside() {
         this.selectedIndex = null
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. In the template, update the `click`-handlers to set the selected index:

   ```html
   <button @click.stop="selectedIndex = 1">Open 1</button>
   <button @click.stop="selectedIndex = 2">Open 2</button>
   ```
4. Also, update the `v-show` condition to render based on the index:

   ```html
   <div v-show="selectedIndex === 1">Content 1</div>
   <div v-show="selectedIndex === 2">Content 2</div>
   ```

Also, don't use a watcher to install a `click`-handler on the `document` because we want to know about the outside-clicks when this component is rendered. It would be more appropriate to add the handler in the `mounted` hook, and then remove in the `beforeDestroy` hook:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.closeIfClickedOutside)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeIfClickedOutside)
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rNyZPJE)

Answer (score 1):

Make an array and loop through it, much easier that way.

```
<template>     
<div id="app">
        <div class="dropdown" v-for="(drop, index) in dropData" :key="index">
      <button @click="openDropdown(index);">{{ drop.title }}</button>
        <div v-show="isOpen === index">{{ drop.content }}</div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          isOpen: null,
          dropData: [
            {
              title: "Hey",
              content: "Hey it's content 1"
            },
              {
              title: "Hey 2",
              content: "Hey it's content 2"
            },
              {
              title: "Hey 3",
              content: "Hey it's content 3"
            },
          ]
        };
      },
     
    methods: {
        openDropdown(idx){
         if (this.isOpen === idx) {
              this.isOpen = null;
            } else {
            this.isOpen = idx;
            }
    
        }
    
    }
    };
    </script>
```